# How to passed the ssh credential in Jenkins Pipeline while deploying to another server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I want to deploy my code as a pipeline, once my testing job is done. How to make the login into another instance from jenkins pipeline.

First I have saved my credentials in Jenkins -

[Jenkins Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0fV4.png)

Also You can check the connection -

[Jenkins SSH Connection Success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmMr0.png)

In pipeline script I am passing -

## !/usr/bin/groovy

pipeline {
    agent any

```
stages {

    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            echo 'Building..'
        }
    }

    stage('Test') {
        steps {
            echo 'Testing..'
        }
    }

    stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            echo 'Deploying....'
            withCredentials([string(credentialsId: '28ebc607-22f5-4fad-91f2-97de971512d3', variable: 'NUSER'),string(credentialsId: '', variable: '')]) {
              sh 'pwd'
              sh 'ls -l'
           }
        }
    }

}
```

}

I am getting the output -

[Jenkins credentials was excepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn7qJ.png)

Error -

ERROR: Credentials '28ebc607-22f5-4fad-91f2-97de971512d3' is of type 'SSH Username with private key' where 'org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.StringCredentials' was expected
Finished: FAILURE

What I am doing wrong ? What is the best way to do it ? Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use the [ssh-agent plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent) and wrap your ssh line with `sshagent (credentials: ['deploy-dev']) { sh 'ssh server do thing' }`

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar use case and I am using the [ssh-agent](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent) plugin for it. You need to create a credential of type SSH and then wrap your code with it.

```
sshagent(credentials: ['jenkins']) {
sh ''
}
```

I have created my credential as example below (using private key)

```
jenkins=[
  username: 'test',
  passphrase: '',
  description : 'SSH credentials',
  type: 'SSH',
  privateKey: ''
]
```